# Return number of records per file after processing multiple files

Tags: awk

I have the following code which runs on multiple tab delimited text files. It sums the amount for a particular field and counts the number of records per file (processing multiple files). Output is Filename,Sum of Field, Count of records - per file. All works well. Only issue is that instead of getting the count of records per file, I am getting a  cumulative count of the whole batch of files that is processed. How can I fix this? I tried replacing 'NR' with 'FNR'. That also didn't work.

I am calling awk through a .bat file

```
awk -f SumColumnRecordCount.awk *.txt
```

This is the code in the awk file

```
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
{ sum[FILENAME] += $42 }
END {
    for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++)
    printf "%s %15d %d\n",ARGV[i],sum[ARGV[i]],NR >>"output.txt"
}
```

Running the .bat file in Windows 7 with GAWK (GNU AWK?)

Comment: I find it interesting how many questions there have been lately asking for a solution that "returns" something (e.g. `Return number of records per file`) but then actually just want to print something instead. I wonder where the terminology mixup is coming from. Do Windows batch files generally talking about "returning" text when they print it? In UNIX what a script returns is it's exit status (aka return status or exit code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a quick adaptation of your code (should work also with GNU<4 and non-GNU awks):

```
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
{ sum[FILENAME] += $42
  last[FILENAME] = FNR }
END {
    for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++)
    printf "%s %15d %d\n",ARGV[i],sum[ARGV[i]],last[ARGV[i]] >>"output.txt"
}
```

---

awk version without arrays (should also work with GNU < 4 and non-GNU awks):

```
BEGIN { 
  FS="\t" 
}
function pr() {
  printf "%s %15d %d\n", f, sum, last >>"output.txt"
}
FNR==1 { 
  if(NR>1) pr()
  sum=last=0
  f=FILENAME
}
{ 
  sum+=$42
  last++
}
END {
  pr()
}
```

--edit--
If one or more input files are completely empty, the second version will not print 0 with the filename.. (thanks @edmorton)

Comment: The semantics of your non-arrays version are incorrect for empty files. Instead of printing the file name with a size of zero, it'll skip the whole file. This kind of thing NEEDS to be done in an END (or ENDFILE) section or needs some other way for pr() to loop through ARGV[] from the last non-empty file processed to the current one.

Comment: Good point, thanks @EdMorton . You are right, the second part is not an answer for completely empty files if they exist..

Comment: @Scrutinizer Both your solutions worked for me. yippee!! could you be kind enough to explain the difference between the array and non-array solution. Is one faster or better than the other. Or are they both the same. Although Steve replied first, i am having trouble running gawk 4.1.1 due to some settings and since ur solution worked fine for me marking this as accepted answer. Hope this is the protocol. Thanks to Steve and you

Comment: @user2473726 Glad to hear. There should be no difference in speed. The first uses a tiny bit more memory, but that is a negligible, largely academic amount. The second does not give the right result for files that are empty (the filename does not get written), if that matters, so maybe the first would be the one to go with..

Answer (score 4):

GNU AWK gives you access to the [ENDFILE function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html%5fnode/BEGINFILE%5f002fENDFILE.html). Therefore, all you really need is:

```
BEGIN {

    FS="\t"
}

{
    sum += $42
}

ENDFILE {

    printf "%s %15d %d\n", FILENAME, sum, FNR > "output.txt"

    sum = 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ed. I should also say that this solution avoids holding all data in memory.

Comment: How come I'm always a few seconds too slow... *+1*. As I noted in my answer, this was introduced in `gawk 4` so isn't available on all platforms out of the box, though.

Comment: @Steve I tried your solution but the in the dos command line it just returns to the dos prompt (meaning it does not do anything). Like Adrian mentioned; maybe my awk/gawk version needs to be above 4 for this to work. I have been unsuccessful in trying to locate a windows installation package for gawk 4.1.1 all i could find was an installation for gawk 3.1.6 at <http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm> Could you be kind enough to point me to a site from where i can get the latest windows 7 installation package; if you are aware of the same. Thanks

Comment: @user2473726: Yeah, you will need the latest version of `gawk` (version 4) to run the above script. Under Windows, I would highly recommend installing the [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) environment. It essentially simulates a Unix environment, allowing you to build tools like the latest `gawk`. You may find [this guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Cygwin.html) useful. The latest tarball can be downloaded [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/). Goodluck!

Comment: @Steve Have installed Cygwin earlier. Its got gawk 4.1.0. However when i run the above code its returns an error `gawk: SumColumnRecordCount.awk:3: fatal: cannot open file *.txt for reading (No such file or directory)`. Guessing i am calling gawk correctly since it returns an error. Tried putting the txt files in the same directory as gawk but still results in same error.

Comment: @user2473726: `cannot open file *.txt` says that your file glob isn't working for some reason (i.e. `gawk` is expecting a file called '*.txt' which doesn't exist). I think you need to escape the asterisk to get your glob working. Try `\*.txt` instead. Alternatively, you may not have the 'glob' cygwin environment variable set. See [here](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html) for details on how to turn it on. Under Linux, I would run the above script like: `gawk -f /path/to/script.awk /path/to/files/*.txt`. HTH.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for all your help. I am a non-techie and working in windows environment. Its a bit too complicated for me to fiddle with the cygwin settings and i don't have linux. Will try to find an alternate solution with awk. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `GNU awk 4` then you can use [`BEGINFILE/ENDFILE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html%5fnode/BEGINFILE%5f002fENDFILE.html) to achieve this:

```
BEGINFILE { sum = 0; FS="\t" }
          { sum += $42 }
ENDFILE   { printf "%s %15d %d\n", FILENAME, sum, NR }
```